# How to filter Activity History Related List based on Activity RecordType

Tags: visualforce, record-type, related-list, event

One solution I thought of doing this would be to create another Activity History related list based on what Event record type I want and then exclude that record type from the original Activity History list.

I tried making a custom related list but first of all it doesn't show as an related list, it's like a block of data that you can put anywhere. The code is copy paste from multiple blogs that I found but none of them work.

Assuming I will succeed in making the custom related list, how can I exclude certain things from the Activity History from SF?

Summary of what I need: two separate related list for activities based on a record type.